# DotNet CLI tools fail using the full framework

Tags: command-line-interface, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am porting a ASP.NET Core DNX command line tool from RC1 to RC2 with dotnet. It uses the full framework 4.5.1. I have stripped it down to a very simple project. My suspicion is that I am missing something basic, but I can't seem to find parallel examples. Apologies in advance if this is a simple fix.

### Steps to reproduce

Here is my project.json file.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.2-alpha001",
  "description": "Tools.Cli Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Test" ],
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "outputName": "dotnet-hello"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils": "1.0.0-preview1-002702"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  }
}
```

Here is my program.cs file.

```
using System;
namespace Tools.Cli
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\x1B[31m" + "Hello World" + "\x1B[39m");
            // The following line causes the error. Commenting out this line allows this to run.
            Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.AnsiColorExtensions.Red("Test"));
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a NuGet package and referencing that from another project as a tool.

### Expected  behavior

run `dotnet hello`
Prints Hello World in red and then Test in red.

This works perfectly without the line to print Test.

### Actual behavior

The following exception is shown. Hello World is not printed.

```
dotnet hello
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. 
    The system cannot find the file specified.
    at Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

At this point I get an error dialog to prompt for debugging.

I have tried this with a number of other assemblies with the same results.

I posted this as an issue on dotnet/cli in GitHub, but haven't received a response.  https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3274

### Environment data

.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview1-002702)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-preview1-002702
 Commit Sha:  6cde21225e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.10586
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64

Comment: Can you close this. I think you received a valid answer from the dotnet/cli team in your ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it wasn't the answer I was looking for, it was addressed at 
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3274

The bottom line is that the .NET CLI team wants all tools to be cross platform, which I understand. It just poses some issues while the cross platform framework doesn't have all the features of the full framework.